# Are Car objects and Dog objects used in real life programs?

Tags: java, oop

While learning about OOP, I have noticed that a lot of the tutorials give examples of objects such as  `Car` objects and `Dog` objects, but I don't know if these kind of objects are used in real life programs.

I think they may be used in a game for example, so if a game have cars and dogs in it, it would use `Car` objects and `Dog` objects, but other than games, are these kind of objects used in real life programs?

Comment: So lets assume you get an answer "Yes.". I bet you will not be satisfied. If you could explain what else you would want to know in that situation, then the question might become celar enough to answer.

Comment: Maybe you can contrast against things you are more familiar with. If I were to ask you "Are variables like MyInt1 and MyFloat2 really used in programs?" What would you answer to that? Now try to see that most users here do not see a difference between your question and mine. Explain what difference you see.

Comment: If a program is concerned with vehicle rentals, or managing boarding kennels, I'd guess it would have `Car` and `Dog` classes. Otherwise, probably not so much.

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't. But in real programs you need to think about relationships between things, and vehicles and animals are things that we already understand.

A Car IS-A Vehicle, a a Car HAS Wheels, a Dog IS-A Animal, and so on.

In a real application maybe the relationships are that an Invoice HAS LineItems and an Employee IS-A Person, but common things like cars and animals are easier to understand when you're learning.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the programmer because what ever you give the object name the final executable will not have any effect. But if you are creating an api you have to take care to see what you are naming them and your api can be used by others.